# Converting HTML to TXT

Tags: python, html, python-requests

I am trying to convert an HTML page to text and store it in a file. I am able to, however there's some random slashes and stars in the file.

Here's the code that I am using

```
import html2text 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests as r 


url = r.get("https://dev.bizlem.io:8082/scorpio1/HANDY_AND_MR_FUEL_OIL_POSITIONS_BASIS_MALTA_AS_OF_TUESDAY_23RD_OCTOBER_2018_1.html")

# print(html2text.html2text(url.text))
web_text = url.text
file = open('text', 'w+')
file.write(html2text.html2text(web_text.replace("** \----", "")))
file.close()
```

here's the output that I get.

```
HANDY_AND_MR_FUEL_OIL_POSITIONS_BASIS_MALTA_AS_OF_TUESDAY_23RD_OCTOBER_2018

FROM: JONNY HAMMOND / AFFINITY TANKERS



HANDY & MR FUEL OIL POSITIONS BASIS MALTA, AS OF TUESDAY, 23RD OCTOBER 2018

===========================================================================



DATE  VESSEL           DWT YR PORT           OPEN  FLEET       COMMENT  

\----  \------           \--- -- ----           \----  \-----       \-------  

23/10 **KRISJANIS VALDEMA 37 07 MALTA           23/10 LATVIAN     SUBS**
```

expected format

```
HANDY_AND_MR_FUEL_OIL_POSITIONS_BASIS_MALTA_AS_OF_TUESDAY_23RD_OCTOBER_2018

FROM: JONNY HAMMOND / AFFINITY TANKERS



HANDY & MR FUEL OIL POSITIONS BASIS MALTA, AS OF TUESDAY, 23RD OCTOBER 2018

===========================================================================



DATE  VESSEL           DWT YR PORT           OPEN  FLEET       COMMENT       

----  ------           --- -- ----           ----  -----       -------       

23/10 KRISJANIS VALDEMA 37 07 MALTA          23/10 LATVIAN     SUBS
```

Comment: Show expecting data

Comment: I edited the question, please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove unnecessary symbols using `replace`:

```
from html2text import html2text
import requests as r

html = r.get("https://dev.bizlem.io:8082/scorpio1/HANDY_AND_MR_FUEL_OIL_POSITIONS_BASIS_MALTA_AS_OF_TUESDAY_23RD_OCTOBER_2018_1.html").text
text = html2text(html).replace('*', '').replace('\-', '')
with open('text.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

Output would be:

```
HANDY_AND_MR_FUEL_OIL_POSITIONS_BASIS_MALTA_AS_OF_TUESDAY_23RD_OCTOBER_2018

FROM: JONNY HAMMOND / AFFINITY TANKERS



HANDY & MR FUEL OIL POSITIONS BASIS MALTA, AS OF TUESDAY, 23RD OCTOBER 2018

===========================================================================



DATE  VESSEL           DWT YR PORT           OPEN  FLEET       COMMENT


---  -----           -- -- ----           ---  ----       ------  

23/10 KRISJANIS VALDEMA 37 07 MALTA           23/10 LATVIAN     SUBS  



25/10 SEAVALOUR          47 07 GREECE         23/10 THENAMARIS  SUBS
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is not necessary to use `beatifulsoup` you can use `html2text` library for rendering. My opinion, It is more reliable for converting html to text.

```
import html2text

htmlForRender = open("https://dev.bizlem.io:8082/scorpio1/HANDY_AND_MR_FUEL_OIL_POSITIONS_BASIS_MALTA_AS_OF_TUESDAY_23RD_OCTOBER_2018_1.html").read()

print html2text.html2text(htmlForRender)
```

Edit for code fix with request library :

```
url = r.get("https://dev.bizlem.io:8082/scorpio1/HANDY_AND_MR_FUEL_OIL_POSITIONS_BASIS_MALTA_AS_OF_TUESDAY_23RD_OCTOBER_2018_1.html")

print html2text.html2text(url)
```

Comment: I tried this solution, however I get `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: {url}` I should really stop blatantly copying answers, I saved the html data into a file, read it through open and parsed it into html2text but the same formatting issue persists.